# Build Table Name in VBA Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to build a table name from user input in access vba.  They will input a certain date that corresponds to a table that already exists.  When I try to do this using string concatenation, I get an Invalid Qualifier error when I try to compile.  The name that I create is declared as a string. Should I declare it as something different? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub RevH()
Dim dte As String, db As Database, tableName As String

Set db = CurrentDb


dte = InputBox("What date was the Data Dump run?", "Please Input a date")

tableName = "FN_DataDump_ALL_" & dte
tableName.MoveFirst
Do While Not tableName.EOF
If tableName("[Client ID]") <> clientTable("[Client ID]") Then
   MsgBox ("No Match.")
   clientTable.MoveNext
Else: MsgBox ("Match.")
End If




Loop







End Sub
```

Comment: You're trying to iterate rows on a String... that will obviously not work!

Comment: Also... MySQL, Access? make up your mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the table you're refering to. Just using a string is not enough.

Something like this

```vb
sub someSub()
Dim dte As String, db As Database, tableName As String, _
    rs as RecordSet, tbl as TableDef, tbl_found as boolean

Set db = currentDb()
dte = InputBox("What date was the Data Dump run?", "Please Input a date")
' Somehow you need to validate that the date is well formed... I leave that to you
tableName = "FN_DataDump_ALL_" & dte
' First check if the table is in the database
tbl_found = false
for each tbl in db.tableDefs
    if tbl.name = tableName then
        tbl_found = true
        exit for
    end if
next tbl
' If the table is not in the database, show an error message and exit the sub
if not tbl_found then
    msgBox("Table not found!")
    exit sub
end if
' Now open the table
set rs = db.OpenRecordset(tableName, dbOpenDynaset, dbEditAdd)
' And NOW you can iterate over the table (the RecordSet)
with rs
    .moveFirst ' Go to the first row of the record set
    do
        ' Do whatever you want to do
        .moveNext
    loop until .EOF
    .close ' Always close recordsets
end with
db.close ' Also, always close database objects (this won't close your database, it will clean-up the object)
end sub
```